# AJAX upload file and text not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using this ajax code for submit form and upload multiple input file. I want to send all form data via ajax. The text input successfully send but file input was not successful post via ajax!
How to change this code?

```
$("#add_order").click(function () {

    //*****get data input
    var formData = new FormData(); 
        formData.append( 'action', 'add_order');
        formData.append( 'customer_name', $('input[name=customer_name]').val());
        formData.append( 'date', $('input[name=date]').val());
        formData.append( 'order_status', $('input:radio[name=order_stautus]').val());
        formData.append( 'total_price', $('input[name=totalprice]').val());
        formData.append( 'quits', $('input[name=quits]').val());
        formData.append( 'debt', $('input[name=debt]').val());
        formData.append( 'desc', $('#desc').val());
        formData.append( 'desc2', $('#desc2').val());

    $.each($("input[type=file]"), function(i, obj) {
        $.each(obj.files,function(j,file){
            formData.append('photo['+i+']', file);
        });
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "includes/ajax/ajax.php",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(response){
           //load json data from server and output message     
           if(response.type == 'error'){ //load json data from server and output message     
               output = '<div class="alert alert-danger">'+response.text+'</div>';
           }else{
               output = '<div class="alert alert-danger">'+response.text+'</div>';
           }
           $("#results").append(output).slideDown();
        } 
    });        
});
```

PHP code for get form data:

```
if($_POST['action']=='add_order'){

    $customer_id = 1;
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $status = $_POST['order_status'];
    $total_price = $_POST['total_price'];
    $quits = $_POST['quits'];
    $debt = $_POST['debt'];
    $desc = $_POST['desc'];
    $desc2 = $_POST['desc2'];

    for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['photo']['name']); $i++) {
        //Get the temp file path
        $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'][$i];

        //Make sure we have a filepath
        if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
          //Setup our new file path
          $newFilePath = "../../uploads/orders/" . $_FILES['photo']['name'][$i];

          //Upload the file into the temp dir
          if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {

            //Handle other code here

          }
        }
      }
```

formData console.log:
[image]

Comment: "I want to get all form data along input files and upload files. But not upload files!" Please clarify. This makes no sense.

Comment: @JoshBjelovuk The question was corrected

Comment: I think you are missing to stringify your object before sending it with ajax. Should be something like this: `JSON.stringify(formData)`. Are you sure that your JSON is syntactically correct? Maybe some console.log can help.

Comment: @MarcoMoschettini console.log Image added to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21045034/1107110), `contentType` must be set to false for ajax file uploads.

And perhaps try naming all your files `photo[]` rather than `photo[n]` to let your PHP server handle the array conversion. See http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php.

Comment: Are you sure you send files using AJAX works properly??

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JSON.stringify:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    data: {form_data: JSON.stringify(formData)},
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

You also need to specify "application/json" instead of "multipart/form-data".
You can check if your json string is correctly formatted with a tool like this: http://jsonlint.com/.

On PHP side you have to decode the incoming data like this:

```
json_decode($_POST[form_data]);
```

Note that *dataType* in your request specifies what are you expecting to receive from server and contentType is the content type *you are sending*.

In your PHP file you have to encode your response in json format accordingly to the json format:

```
echo json_encode($my_response);
```

**EDIT**:
Here's some hint on accessing json object on the PHP side:

```
<?php

$my_json = json_decode($_POST["form_data"]);
$action = $my_json["action"];

/*
 DO STUFF
*/

$response = array('error' => "My error");
if(/* all is correct */)
    $response = array('response' => "My response", 'id' => 3);

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Comment: Thank you. It possible for me to get a php sample code?